# Stop Safari from wiping middle tabs on restart

Tags: macos, safari, monterey

When I have many tabs open in Safari, 10+, and then quit and relaunch Safari, all the middle tabs (e.g. not the first 4, not the last 4) will not be present in the new window.

How can I make sure that they will always remain?